# How to create a stars review system in Excel for a table?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new in VBA, and I got a task to find a way to implement the 5 stars review like in Amazon/Ebay with graphical stars itself for an excel table. Is it possible that? or even to combine with other technologies.

All I need are some hits, how to do that, and where to start.

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use?

Comment: Maybe you can propose your client to use Excel built-in *Condition Formatting*? There are 5-grad rating sets, but they do not use stars.

Comment: There are conditional formats that do so dependant on version tho.

Comment: There are stars in Excel when you look on the `Insert` tab for `Shapes`. Yet, it would be a major task programming task to generate for each value 5 stars, fill them will yellow or not, size them correctly, align them correctly, and finally put them in a nice fitting spot on the sheet (next to the number value). Sounds a bit steep for a first VBA programming task. But if you are up for it you can create some stars and record the macros (just to get started).

Comment: @J.Chomel   I use the 2013 version. The client used before  built-in condition formatting, but they asked me if is it possible to use stars to make it more user friendly and more modern.  And they particular want to be the same as in Amazon or ebay...maybe its possible to combine with another technology like php/js?

Comment: @Ralph yeah, it seems to be a hard one, and for me personal VBA is looking so unfriendly.. How about to embed in that worksheet some JS scripts to realize that? is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment I would like to merely sketch the basic concept of doing such rating manually. Since I couldn't fit it in a comment box I'll put it here as a conceptual draft of what it might look like (this is not an attempt to be a solution):

(1) Getting a star on a sheet is as simple as that

```
Sheet1.Shapes.AddShape Type:=msoShape5pointStar, _
    Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=7.2, Height:=7.2
```

(2) Getting four more stars next to it should be simple enough by adding the width of prior star(s) and some extra space to the `Left`.

(3) Color your star(s) yellow or white with presets (Office 2010+)

```
.ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset12
```

(4) In order to locate the stars on the sheet next to the cell containing the value which should be rated you can use the following methods assuming that the value is in cell A1:

```
.Left = Sheets(1).Range("A1").Left + Sheets(1).Range("A1").Width
```

Of course, there is a bit more to it than the above. You will have to determine the range of cells for which you want to create stars. Also, if someone adds a column or changes the width of a column then all stars might get changed and will have to be drawn again. Also, you'll have to make sure that the column B is wide enough to hold all the stars. But that's the basic concept (as I would attempt to do it).

Comment: There's also the question of determining how many stars to render for any given item. The code you propose deals with the rendering itself, and rendering an arbitrary number can be done with loops, but how will the program know how many stars to create for the table item it is working on?